# DateTime column in CSV opened in Excel formats to time only

Tags: excel, csv, import-csv

This has been driving me nuts for a while now.

If I have a CSV file with the following data:

```
time,isBot,userAgent
07/12/2019 11:27:25.339,true,facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
07/12/2019 11:27:24.471,true,facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
07/12/2019 11:07:12.161,true,Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/3~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
```

Gets formatted as...

```
time     isBot    userAgent
27:25.3  TRUE     facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
27:24.4  TRUE     facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
7:12.1   TRUE     Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/3~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
```

Any idea on how I can change this default behavior? It's been frustrating me for a while now.

Update 1: I went through the data file to remove the milliseconds from the time column.

```
time,isBot,userAgent
07/12/2019 11:27:25,true,facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
07/12/2019 11:27:24,true,facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
07/12/2019 11:07:12,true,Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/3~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
```

And that formats out the way I would expect it.

```
time                     isBot    userAgent
7/12/2019 11:27:25.339   TRUE     facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
7/12/2019 11:27:24.471   TRUE     facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
7/12/2019 11:07:12.161   TRUE     Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/3~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)
```

This gives me the format I want but sacrifices the precision of capturing milliseconds.

Comment: You may want to specify the format; it looks like the time with the miliseconds is throwing off the default/general format.  `columns(1).numberformat = "mm/dd/yyyy HH:nn:ss"`... without being too sure about milliseconds, i believe you might need to loop through the CSV file and take `right(left(cells(i,1),value,insrt(cells(i,1).value,","-1),4)` and append that

Comment: No, I want to keep the milliseconds component of the data. I did a test where I removed the the milliseconds and Excel formatted the date correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to open the file as is and use a macro to split the data specifying the preferred format.  Have you given any thought/effort to VBA?

Comment: Here, when I tried it, even with just **OPEN**ing the `csv` file, the correct value was read.  It was merely a matter of formatting that column to have it display with the msec.

Comment: @Cyril, I hadn't considered writing a macro as these are CSV files from sources beyond my control usually. Are you suggesting something like a macro in a personal macro library watches for CSV files to be opened and then scanning them for columns with date time values with milliseconds to change column formatting? That could work, but I'd rather exhaust an easier approach. :)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are correct, it's a formatting issue, not a data loss problem. But I don't want to have to reformat one or more columns every time I open a CVS that has date time values that contain milliseconds.

Comment: I don't know of a method to change the default date/time format to include msec.  You'll have to either develop a VBA solution, or possibly use Power Query or the legacy import wizard, and designate that column as **Text** when you import it.

Answer (score 1):

I also facing for the CSV , but when i just double clicked to that excel colmun it's showing me the desired format . It means its not due to any data loss